# What is the counter variable in a Python loop called?

Tags: python

In languages where `for` loops are constructed similarly to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {}
```

the variable `i` in this example seems generally to [be referred to](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86904/why-do-most-of-us-use-i-as-a-loop-counter-variable) as a "counter variable".

What is the equivalent technical name for the loop variable in Python, where `for` loops are more like `for each`?

```
for i in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
```

Here "counter variable" seems far less obvious a name.

Comment: See http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/for_loops.html

Comment: The docs generally refer to them as “items”: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: @quantik that link seems totally irrelevant.

Comment: I've always called it the "loop variable." In the C family of languages, it just happened to be used as a counter a lot of the time.

Comment: If it's used as an index, or represents the number of current iteration or similar things, it can safely be called "counter", to my mind.

Comment: @JeffMercado's suggestion of "loop variable" wins the race for me. Obvious what it's referring to. Like it.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Python `for` loops are *not like C `for` loops*. There is no *counter*, because the Python construct is a [*For each* construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop). Also see the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements):

> The `for` statement in Python differs a bit from what you may be used to in C or Pascal. Rather than always iterating over an arithmetic progression of numbers (like in Pascal), or giving the user the ability to define both the iteration step and halting condition (as C), Python’s `for` statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence.

The construct takes an [*iterable*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) actually, and keeps looping until the end of the iterator is reached. It lets you specify one or more names to assign the next object from the iterator to; the Python documentation calls this the *target list*.

See the [`for` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> Each item in turn is assigned to the target list using the standard rules for assignments

Because the target list is assigned elements from the iterable, you could also refer to the variable in context of the iterable. For a list, you can talk about the *list element*, for looping over a file, the target is assigned the next *line*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it something along the lines of a "placeholder variable/s" as in "the variable that is a placeholder for the items iterated over by the for loop".

It could, as @Ajax1234 pointed out, be a placeholder for a list element, or a dictionary element, a file, almost object that could be in a selection of items iterated over in a for loop.

It could also be noted that in using the word 'placeholder' I'm being rather literal - it can be just about anything you want, eg:

```
a = 'a'
b = 'b'
c = 'c'
d = 'd'

print(f'a = {a}')
list2 = [a, b, c, d]
for a in list2:
    print(a)
print(f'a = {a}')
```

Outputs:

```
a = a
a
b
c
d
a = d
```

Note that that placeholder variable actually holds the last object iterated over, in this case `a` is reassigned the strings 'a','b','c','d'.

Answer (score 0):

In this example

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {}
```

The `i` is used to help determine when a loop should end/stop iteration.

Python does this automagically, behind the scenes for you.

The variable `i` in this example:

```
for i in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
```

is a placeholder to hold the values that are being iterated over.

It is customary for the `i` variable to be called by names such as:

- target variable
- iteration variable

Behind the scenes, when the for loop runs out of items to iterate over, a StopIteration condition is raised and the for loop will exit.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) references this:

```
for_stmt ::=  “for” target_list “in” expression_list “:” suite
              [“else” “:” suite]
```

> The expression list is evaluated once; it should yield an iterable
>   object. An iterator is created for the result of the expression_list.
>   The suite is then executed once for each item provided by the
>   iterator, in the order returned by the iterator. Each item in turn is
>   assigned to the **target list** using the standard rules for
>   assignments (see Assignment statements), and then the suite is
>   executed. When the items are exhausted (which is immediately when the
>   sequence is empty or an iterator raises a StopIteration exception),
>   the suite in the else clause, if present, is executed, and the loop
>   terminates.

**NOTE**: `target_list` does NOT mean the item is an actual list.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the term "controlled variable", since the loop controls its value. Programmers of most languages seem to understand this, though I can hardly claim it's an industry standard.